# More reliable method to get specific JSON value using Python

Tags: python, json

Based on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697626/get-the-value-of-specific-json-element-in-python) a certain JSON value can be found using `print data[u'X'][50][u'Z']`

`data[u'X']` results in:

```
{
  "X" : [ {
    "A" : "B",
    ...
  }, {
    ...
  }, {
    "C" : "D",
  } ]
}
```

Applying the *integer method* means that every part that is separated by a comma, e.g. `"element" : [ { "name" : "value", ... },` needs to be counted until the required piece has been found, in this case number 50.

What if the JSON structure will be changed in the future? Does this mean that the integer should be updated every time?

In my opinion this method is fragile. How to make it more reliable?

**Attempts**

`print data[u'X'][0]` results in:

```
{u'A': u'B', u'C': u'D'}
```

while

`print data[u'X'][u'A']`

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print data[u'beans'][u'modelerType']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Comment: Based on your sample, `print data[u'X'][50][u'Z']` will be a `KeyError`. What is *"the integer method"* to which you refer? Do you mean indexing into a list (in which case, it certainly does not need *"to be counted until the required piece has been found"* - indexing is `O(1)`)?

Comment: Yes, if you structure changes, your hard-coded path into that structure likely has to change too. You have a route through a structure, so if the structure changes, your route has to change accordingly. You usually don't hardcode the route; you usually pick landmarks instead, but your question is too broad and devoid of detail to give you suitable landmarks to traverse by.

Comment: @MartijnPieters question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of collections in JSON, arrays and objects [(see the API for more info)](http://jsonapi.org/format/)

For example, a list of items:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x[2] // Returns 'c'
```

And an object:

```
x = {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 30}
x['b'] // Returns 20
```

So assuming you use an object to store the data than you won't need an index number at all, just the name of the property. If you use the list, than you will have to store the list index.

It is possible to store an array in an object and vice versa. For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c": [30, 40, 50]}]
x[0] // Returns 1
x[3] // Returns {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c": [30, 40, 50]}
x[3]['a'] // Returns 10
x[3]['c'][2] // Returns 50
```

Comment: When strings are used it results in `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode`

Comment: @utrecht: note the difference between `{` and `[`. With an object (where you can use strings/unicode) you have to use `{`. With an array you have to use numbers as indices. Within python it's the difference between a `list()` and a `dict()` which are also denounced by a `[]` and `{}` respectively.

Comment: So in this case integers should be used always? It is not possible to make it less fragile by using strings?

Comment: If you want to use strings, use objects. If you have no need for strings, use an array. Note that the downside of objects is the inconsistent sort order, so if you need ordering you will have to use an array.

Comment: I cannot change the json file. I am trying to get specific value from a jmx page.

Comment: Comparing your example with the sample from the question, e.g. `print data[u'X'][0]` should output the same as `print data[u'X'][u'Y']` right?

Comment: No, it's either `data['X']['Y']` if `data['X']` is an object, or it's `data['X'][0]` if `data['X']` is an array instead. If you cannot change the json file than you'll just have to loop through it to be sure.

Comment: You mean read every array, if there is a match find the number of loops and use that?

Comment: What you are trying to do exactly is still not a 100% clear to me, but if you're walking through an array you will have to use the indices which will depend on the amount of items. So you will probably have to do something like this: `for x in data['X']: if 'Z' in x: print x['Z']`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closer to what you're looking for:

```
models = ['JvmMetrics', 'MyMetrics']
filtered = filter(ldata['beans'], lambda x: x['modelerType'] in models)
```

It's unlikely that there's a better way unless you want to build another dict from the JMX response.